# Design Pattern To Implement Bit Data/Operator In NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sql

I realize that NDB / Google Datastore does not support bit data type and supporting operators.

But does anyone have any suggestions a workaround.

My data is a tree of categories and the user can select multiple categories. Ideal implementation would have been to store as a single number and to perform bitwise and operation to find match.

Also, does anyone know the NDB/Datastore roadmap?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't yell. Thank you.

Comment: This smells of premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some bitwise support, bitstring is an excellent library (version 2.2 works, with a [patch](https://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/issues/attachmentText?id=116&aid=1160000000&name=mmap.patch&token=Wkic9ZlnaFhP8rxsj824IjXx63g%3A1363134285743)). However, you will not be able to query based on the individual bits, just the entire bitstring as a whole.

If the number of categories each user would potentially select is only a handful, consider using a repeated property, with one list entry for each category selected. This allows for easy queries and won't eat your quota as much as you think.

Remember that the majority of the cost comes from reads and writes. Queries are cheap as long as you limit the number of entities you fetch each time; it doesn't matter if you have 100 or 1,000,000 entities of that kind.

GAE requires some out-of-the-box thinking when it comes to storing data (here, denormalization is sometimes a good thing). I advise reading the datastore docs top to bottom so you get a deep understanding of how queries and indexes work. There's also a Google I/O presentation about how it works under the hood.

As jterrace alluded to, sometimes you have to wonder if the time spent *developing* an optimal solution is more than the extra cost of a less efficient, but easier, solution.

Comment: And what seems like an optimal solution on one platform may not be the case on another - case in point bitfields and indexability/searchability on appengine ;-)

Comment: Cool Thanks a mil! Repeated property - I did not know this! Cool! That should work! About out-of-the-box thinking.. Very true... I have been doing normalized SQL design for ages.. GAE does require some rewiring on my end.. Thanks a mil!

Comment: Just be careful with repeated properties. If your queries involve more than one repeated property you can run into exploding indexes (they're as scary as they sound). [Read more](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes#Index_Limits)

Comment: Thanks .... Will keep this in mind. Fortunately for now my table does not require more than one repeated property. I will see how it plays out. warning noted